# Using Robot Framework and Seleniumlibrary, extracting data and saving to txt file

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am currently developing a test automation using Using Robot Framework and Seleniumlibrary. My problem is taking the links on the website and saving them in a txt file. Is this possible? If possible, how is it done?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to grab? the url? the text (e.g. "click here")?

Anyway, after deciding what you want to write in the file, you can use the library "Operating system" to write the contents of a variable to a file:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Create%20File

Comment: I'm trying to get the text of the list items and save it to the file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done any research,j and it's not clear what part of the problem you need help with. To start, I recommend reading about [Get webelements](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20WebElements) in the SeleniumLibrary documentation, and [Append to file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Append%20To%20File) in the OperatingSystem documentation.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem thanks to the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with [Create File](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Create%20File). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
all_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for a in all_links:
  print(a.text) #text of the link
  print(a.get_attribute("href")) #href of the link
```

instead of print, write out to a text file as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm working on the `.robot` file.